# deliver a quantum register to/from a function in qiskit

Tags: quantum-state, qiskit

Can I create a function in qiskit which receive a quantum register as an argument, and/or returns a quantum register?
In the example below, I created a quantum register, and a quantum circuit which works on it in the main function. I deliver this register to a function called "test" which chooses a random state for this register, but when I perform a measurement in the main function, it seems like the original state was not effected by the operation of the function since the measurement gives:

counts:
{'000': 1024}

Can any one explain this? Is there a correct way to do so? 
Thanks

````
#######################################################################
def test(n, QP, CP):

    QC_B = QuantumCircuit(QP, CP)

    # choose a random state
    for i in range(n):
        if (np.random.randint(2) == 1):
            QC_B.x(QP[i])
        else:
            QC_B.iden(QP[i])
    QC_B.barrier()

    simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
    result = execute(QC_B, simulator)

    return QP


#######################################################################
def main():

    N = 3
    Q = QuantumRegister(N)
    C = ClassicalRegister(N)
    QC_A = QuantumCircuit(Q, C)

    # ... 
    # ... QC_A perform some operations on Q...
    # ... 

    QC_A.iden(Q)
    Q = test(N, Q, C)

    QC_A.measure(Q, C)

    simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
    # Execute and get counts
    result = execute(QC_A, simulator).result()
    counts = result.get_counts(QC_A)
    print("counts: ")
    print(counts)
    return

```
````

Comment: Quantum Register is just a placeholder. When you add the X gate to your circuit `QC_B` in function `test`, it's added to your circuit `QC_B` and not to the register `QP`. You should consider returning circuit `QC_B` from this function and then make measurement on this circuit in your main function.

Comment: @ss09 Thanks for the reply. You are right, but my question is more general, and this is just a simple example for it. The general question is - Can I call a function and give to it a quantum register, and the function will work on it and return the modified register to the caller which will continue to work on the modified state of the register?

Comment: AFAIK, we can't operate on registers outside of a circuit. You could pass circuit as a parameter to a function, manipulate the circuit inside the function and then return it to the caller which will then have an altered circuit. But we can't do same thing with the register since there's nothing called "modifying a register".

Comment: A small clue is if we look at your `test` function, it only manipulates `QC_B` circuit and the register `QP` is actually left untouched and which is expected. We manipulate a qubit inside a circuit. A QuantumRegister just provides a placeholder for said number of qubits using which we can create a QuantumCircuit.

Comment: @ss09 I changed the "test" function and now it calls execute, to "fix" the fact that the function does not touch the qubits. The result is unsurprisingly the same.      So just to be sure, I can't return a register with a certain state, and I can't give a register to a function and expect that it will modify the state of the qubits of the register and that the change will be valid in the calling function?

Comment: There are two problems I see with your approach: 1. We can't manipulate registers directly whether inside `test` function or `main`. It's not supposed to be that way. What you're trying to do is "manipulate the circuit" and not "manipulate the register". 2. Even when you add execute to your circuit `QC_B`, you're doing it inside the function `test` and also not printing its counts. You won't see its effect until you print counts of that circuit.